# cpp11 gives error "object not found" for all c++ functions

Tags: r, rcpp11

I am trying to write a package using C++11 and have succeeded in writing code that runs correctly when sourced with `cpp11::cpp_source()`. However, when I try to load the functions using `devtools`, I get an error stating that the function cannot be found: `Error in <function> : object <function name> not found`.

I used the following sample tutorial to create a minimal example: https://www.r-bloggers.com/2023/05/using-cpp11-r-package-and-llvm-on-ubuntu/. The files I used for the example are:

`code.cpp`

```cpp
#include <cpp11.hpp>
#include <cpp11/doubles.hpp>
using namespace cpp11;
    
[[cpp11::register]] doubles_matrix<> Xt(doubles_matrix<> X)
{
    int NX = X.nrow();
    int MX = X.ncol();
    writable::doubles_matrix<> R(MX, NX);
    for (int i = 0; i < MX; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < NX; j++)
        {
            R(i, j) = X(j, i);
        }
    }
    return R;
}
```

`cpp11dummypackage-package.R`

```
#' @useDynLib cpp11dummypackage, .registration = TRUE
NULL

#' Transpose a matrix
#' @export
#' @rdname Xt
#' @param X numeric matrix
#' @return numeric matrix
#' @examples
#' set.seed(1234)
#' X <- matrix(rnorm(4), nrow = 2, ncol = 2)
#' X
#' cpp11_Xt(X)
cpp11_Xt <- function(X) {
  Xt(X)
}
```

Running `devtools::load_all()` appears to run correctly, however, running `cpp11_Xt()` gives the error:

```
Error in Xt(X) : object '_cpp11dummypackage_Xt' not found.
```

I have tried updating R and installing on a different system, but the same error persists.

Answer (score 0):

I worked out what I was missing.

The lines

```
#' @useDynLib cpp11dummypackage, .registration = TRUE
NULL
```

instruct Roxygen2 to add a line on using DynLib to the NAMESPACE file in the package (which in turn is what loads the C++ functions to be called from R).
The `NULL` is important as otherwise it seems to cause Roxygen2 to skip the comment (this is speculation on my part, but adding it in did fix the problem).

I then needed to run `devtools::document()` in order to correctly generate the NAMESPACE file.